# Selection bias in postmortem data and creating an artificial earlier study endpoint

Tags: selection-bias

I want to analyze postmortem (neuropathology) data from dementia patients who are part of a larger ongoing observational study. At the time of the data freeze (i.e. the time at which I access the data), some patients have died and are thus eligible for my dataset, whereas others are still alive and thus not included.

I worry that this introduces a selection bias - that individuals who score higher on variable of interest X (in my case: educational attainment) are more often alive and thus overlooked, creating a distorted relationship of X with neuropathology (Y) in my dataset.

I thought of a potential solution, which is to set an “artificial data freeze” on an earlier timepoint (e.g. 5 years before), selecting dementia patients who have deceased by then, and in addition selectively continue to follow alive dementia patients who were already included in the study by that time. Note that I will thus ignore all dementia cases included after the artificial data freeze. At the “true data freeze” (5 years later / the present), at least some of those selectively followed dementia patients will have deceased as well, and be eligible for my dataset.

My question is: do you agree that this approach (at the cost of a smaller sample size) could reduce the potential selection bias? Does it make any sense? And are you aware of any literature on this topic?

Thank you so much,

AnnaC

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're investigating.  What is your outcome and how is it measured?  Are you interested in the relationship of any variables to your outcome, or are you just seeking to describe the population you're seeing?